# TeXmaker spellchecker is set to use en_UK, but it still accepts en_US spelling

Tags: texmaker, spelling, dictionaries

As the title says, I have TeXmaker set to use the en_UK dictionary.
This dictionary was manually copied from the LibreOffice's website (https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/english-dictionaries), and I saved it in the default path of my TeXmaker dictionary: /usr/share/myspell/dicts/.

This seems to work fine, the problem is that besides en_UK, TeXmaker is also accepting en_US spelling. For example, if I write "center" nothing is highlighted but I would expect it to, and "centre" should be suggested as alternative.

Using grep to verify the contents of the dictionary I got the following results.

```
$ grep center /usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_GB.dic
(nothing was returned)

$ grep centre /usr/share/myspell/dicts/en_GB.dic
barycentre/SMW
centre/GDRMJ3WoSp
centreboard/SM
centreboarder
centrefire/SM
centrefold/SM
centreline/MS
centrement
centremost
centrepiece/SM
centrepin/SM
epicentre/MSO
hypocentre/SM
jobcentre/SM
megacentre/SM
metacentre/SMW
multicentre/WO
off-centre
precentress
recentre
self-centred
self-centredly/M
self-centredness
subcentre
supercentre
```

So if I understand correctly, the word "center" is not in the dictionary and should be highlighted by spellchecker, right? What am I missing?

Comment: no idea about texmaker but does it add the names of latex enviornments to its dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Do you mean that something should be added to the en_UK.dic file? I don't know much about latex environments...

Comment: I mean `\begin{center}` is a core latex command so it wouldn't surprise me if the spell checker knows such words in addition to the specified  natural language, but I know nothing about that editor.

Comment: That makes sense, because this behaviour is not consistent. I can find words for which the US version is highlighted (like honor vs honour). But characterized and characterised are both accepted, regardless what dictionary I select (en_UK or en_US)..

Comment: lots of UK English dictionaries (notably the Oxford English Dictionary) have always accepted ize endings